# Regular expression for alphanumeric and underscores

Tags: regex

Is there a regular expression which checks if a string contains only upper and lowercase letters, numbers, and underscores?

Comment: It is a pity that different regex engines have different means to match alphanumerics. A question like this (rather vague, with no language/regex flavor indicated) requires a very long, or at least a very organized answer dwelling on each flavor.

Comment: I checked this [regex](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/ce2033df9fc2), and it works in most regex engine.

Answer (score 1242):

To match a string that contains *only* those characters (or an empty string), try

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$"
```

This works for .NET regular expressions, and probably a lot of other languages as well.

Breaking it down:

```
^ : start of string
[ : beginning of character group
a-z : any lowercase letter
A-Z : any uppercase letter
0-9 : any digit
_ : underscore
] : end of character group
* : zero or more of the given characters
$ : end of string
```

If you don't want to allow empty strings, use `+` instead of `*`.

---

As others have pointed out, some regex languages have a shorthand form for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. In the .NET regex language, you can turn on ECMAScript behavior and use `\w` as a shorthand (yielding `^\w*$` or `^\w+$`). Note that in other languages, and by default in .NET, `\w` is somewhat broader, and will match other sorts of Unicode characters as well (thanks to Jan for pointing this out). So if you're really intending to match **only** those characters, using the explicit (longer) form is probably best.

Comment: If you ever go to Germany or if you ever see just about any German text you'll see what I'm saying.

Comment: \w and [A-Za-z0-9_] are not equivalent in most regex flavors. \w includes letters with diacritics, letters from other scripts, etc.

Comment: The original question did say "upper and lowercase letters", so it would seem that "letters" from non-Latin scripts should match.

Comment: `[\p{upper}\p{lower}\p{gc=Number}_]` is all you need to do this right, presuming there are no combining characters.

Comment: I've seen this in many places, but it still allows the '$' character for me.  All other special characters are blocked that I've tested so far.

Comment: I get "No ending delimiter '^' found", when I use this pattern with preg_match

Comment: It looks like preg_match requires your pattern to be enclosed with delimiters, which are normally slashes. So you would need "/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/". See this question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445133/no-ending-delimiter-found-error. See also this page: http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/108241-no-ending-delimiter-found-in-what-have-i-done/

Comment: What's going on with all the up-votes. This is not correct. It only works for English. If you are going to make an edit, EDIT it. Don't add on an "Edit:", just make it correct.

Comment: I like how you broke down the regular expressions too

Comment: Upvote for actually breaking down and explaining the pattern! Well done!

Comment: @heisenberg YES. x100. I took formal languages a few years ago and this brought it all back.

Comment: what about characters like "öäüßÿ...."  --> Characters in other languages, which have accents etc.?

Comment: `+` doesn't work on some grep implementations. The lexicon is limited, be carefull.

Answer (score 469):

There's a lot of verbosity in here, and I'm deeply against it, so, my conclusive answer would be:

```
/^\w+$/
```

`\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, which is pretty much what you want (unless we introduce [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) to the mix).

Using the `+` quantifier you'll match one or more characters. If you want to accept an empty string too, use `*` instead.

Comment: `\w` isn’t usually restricted to ASCII alone.

Comment: English is not the only language in the world, so this should be the accepted answer, not the `[a-z]` and its variations. `\w` will capture non-latin characters too. Like `šēēā` or `кукареку`

Comment: Validated on page 318 of the O'Reilly "Mastering Regular Expressions"

Comment: `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` in ECMAScript (i.e. what runs in your modern Web browser), implying both are restricted to ASCII there.

Comment: If you're using Javascript, you may want `/\p{L}/u` (note the unicode flag). Demo: `"é".match(/\w/)` ❌, `"é".match(/\p{L}/u)` ✅

Answer (score 51):

You want to check that each character matches your requirements, which is why we use:

```
[A-Za-z0-9_]
```

And you can even use the shorthand version:

```
\w
```

Which is equivalent (in some regex flavors, so make sure you check before you use it). Then to indicate that the entire string must match, you use:

```
^
```

To indicate the string must start with that character, then use

```
$
```

To indicate the string must end with that character. Then use

```
\w+ or \w*
```

To indicate "1 or more", or "0 or more". Putting it all together, we have:

```
^\w*$
```

Comment: \w and [A-Za-z0-9_] are not equivalent in most regex flavors.  \w includes letters with diacritics, letters from other scripts, etc.

Comment: They are equivalent with ECMAScript.

Answer (score 49):

Although it's more verbose than `\w`, I personally appreciate the readability of the full POSIX character class names ( http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm#special ), so I'd say:

```
^[[:alnum:]_]+$
```

However, while the documentation at the above links states that `\w` will "Match any character in the range 0 - 9, A - Z and a - z (equivalent of POSIX [:alnum:])", I have not found this to be true. Not with `grep -P` anyway. You need to explicitly include the underscore if you use `[:alnum:]` but not if you use `\w`. You can't beat the following for short and sweet:

```
^\w+$
```

Along with readability, using the POSIX character classes (http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) means that your regex can work on non ASCII strings, which the range based regexes won't do since they rely on the underlying ordering of the ASCII characters which may be different from other character sets and will therefore exclude some non-ASCII characters (letters such as œ) which you might want to capture.

Answer (score 43):

Um...question:  Does it need to have at least one character or no?  Can it be an empty string?

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$
```

Will do at least one upper or lower case alphanumeric or underscore.  If it can be zero length, then just substitute the *+* for ***:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_]*$
```

If [diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) need to be included (such as cedilla - ç) then you would need to use the word character which does the same as the above, but includes the diacritic characters:

```
^\w+$
```

Or

```
^\w*$
```

Comment: Well now that you mention it, I also missed a whole bunch of other French characters...

Comment: \w is the same as [\w] with less typing effort

Comment: Yeah, you still need the + or * and the ^ and $ - \w just checks that it contains word characters, not that it *only* contains word characters...

Comment: oddly, this still allows the $ sign.

Comment: @Induster, it's because of what BenAlabaster just pointed out

Answer (score 25):

Use

```
^([A-Za-z]|[0-9]|_)+$
```

...if you want to be explicit, or:

```
^\w+$
```

...if you prefer concise (Perl syntax).

Comment: When dealing with languages like Portuguese, better use the ```^\w+$``` to match letters with accent.

Answer (score 22):

In computer science, an alphanumeric value often means the first character is not a number, but it is an alphabet or underscore. Thereafter the character can be `0-9`, `A-Z`, `a-z`, or underscore (`_`).

Here is how you would do that:

Tested under PHP:

```php
$regex = '/^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z\d_]*$/'
```

Or take

```
^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z\d_]*$
```

and place it in your development language.

Answer (score 15):

Use lookaheads to do the "at least one" stuff.  Trust me, it's much easier.

Here's an example that would require 1-10 characters, containing at least one digit and one letter:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9]{1,10}$
```

*Note*: I could have used *\w*, but then ECMA/Unicode considerations come into play, increasing the character coverage of the \w "word character".

Comment: How would we do if we want to add _ and - to the list?

Answer (score 13):

This works for me. I found this in the O'Reilly's "Mastering Regular Expressions":

```
/^\w+$/
```

Explanation:

- ^ asserts position at start of the string

  - \w+ matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
  - "+" Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- $ asserts position at the end of the string

Verify yourself:

```js
const regex = /^\w+$/;
const str = `nut_cracker_12`;
let m;

if ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Try these multi-lingual extensions I have made for string.

IsAlphaNumeric - The string must contain at least one alpha (letter in Unicode range, specified in charSet) and at least one number (specified in numSet). Also, the string should consist only of alpha and numbers.

IsAlpha - The string should contain at least one alpha (in the language charSet specified) and consist only of alpha.

IsNumeric - The string should contain at least one number (in the language numSet specified) and consist only of numbers.

The charSet/numSet range for the desired language can be specified. The Unicode ranges are available on *[Unicode Chart](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/%7Etomw/java/unicode.html)*.

API:

```csharp
public static bool IsAlphaNumeric(this string stringToTest)
{
    // English
    const string charSet = "a-zA-Z";
    const string numSet = @"0-9";

    // Greek
    //const string charSet = @"\u0388-\u03EF";
    //const string numSet = @"0-9";

    // Bengali
    //const string charSet = @"\u0985-\u09E3";
    //const string numSet = @"\u09E6-\u09EF";

    // Hindi
    //const string charSet = @"\u0905-\u0963";
    //const string numSet = @"\u0966-\u096F";

    return Regex.Match(stringToTest, @"^(?=[" + numSet + @"]*?[" + charSet + @"]+)(?=[" + charSet + @"]*?[" + numSet + @"]+)[" + charSet + numSet +@"]+$").Success;
}

public static bool IsNumeric(this string stringToTest)
{
    //English
    const string numSet = @"0-9";

    //Hindi
    //const string numSet = @"\u0966-\u096F";

    return Regex.Match(stringToTest, @"^[" + numSet + @"]+$").Success;
}

public static bool IsAlpha(this string stringToTest)
{
    //English
    const string charSet = "a-zA-Z";

    return Regex.Match(stringToTest, @"^[" + charSet + @"]+$").Success;
}
```

Usage:

```csharp
// English
string test = "AASD121asf";

// Greek
//string test = "Ϡϛβ123";

// Bengali
//string test = "শর৩৮";

// Hindi
//string test = @"क़लम३७ख़";

bool isAlphaNum = test.IsAlphaNumeric();
```

Comment: @Shah : I have added the only alphabets (and only numbers too).

Answer (score 9):

The following regex matches alphanumeric characters and underscore:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$
```

For example, in Perl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $arg1 = $ARGV[0];

# Check that the string contains *only* one or more alphanumeric chars or underscores
if ($arg1 !~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/) {
  print "Failed.\n";
} else {
    print "Success.\n";
}
```

Comment: The pattern in your code is correct, but the pattern above only checks a single instance.

Comment: That was intentional, code sample was intended as a clarifying usage in actually checking a string. Also why code has the beginning and end of line markers as well which are not in the regex example.

Comment: @Windows programmer - not sure if you're just trying to be humorous or clever, but alphanumeric specifically refers to the latin alphabet and arabic numerals, so wouldn't include ñ or any of the other special chars you've referenced in the comments here.

Comment: @Jay: I think your answer would be a lot clearer if the regex above the source code snippet was the proper regex, rather than a partial regex.  People who don't know Perl will look at your regex, but not at the Perl snippet.

Comment: @Windows programmer - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphanumeric - latin *alphabet*, not "latin character set" which is what includes diacritics etc. Purely a semantics issue, but I personally go with the common usage of the term alphanumeric as A-Z and 0-9.

Comment: @Jan - added the full regex anyway, though there's already an accepted answer so it probably doesn't matter. Helps if people specify the language they're working in in the first place so we don't have to guess ;)

Comment: ñ is a letter of the alphabet in Spanish, including in Latin America.

Comment: "I would like to have a regular expression that checks if a string contains only upper and lowercase letters, numbers, and underscores" doesn't limit it to Latin letters. "The following regex matches alphanumeric characters and underscore" doesn't limit it to Latin letters. "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$" fails.

Answer (score 6):

This should work in most of the cases.

`/^[\d]*[a-z_][a-z\d_]*$/gi`

And by most I mean,

```
abcd       True
abcd12     True
ab12cd     True
12abcd     True

1234       False
```

#### Explanation

1. `^ ... $` - match the pattern starting and ending with
2. `[\d]*` - match zero or more digits
3. `[a-z_]` - match an alphabet or underscore
4. `[a-z\d_]*` - match an alphabet or digit or underscore
5. `/gi` - match globally across the string and case-insensitive

Comment: The original question didn't have a requirement that the letter shall be present.

Comment: Which letter are you talking about? My regex contains the one asked in the question. Alphabets, numbers, underscore

Comment: the `1234` is the word from the language requested by author. Your language is more restrictive.

Comment: It should match numbers(1234) as well like this [regex](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/ce2033df9fc2).

Answer (score 5):

For those of you looking for unicode alphanumeric matching, you might want to do something like:

```
^[\p{L} \p{Nd}_]+$
```

Further reading is at *[Unicode Regular Expressions](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/)* (Unicode Consortium) and at *[Unicode Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)* (Regular-Expressions.info).

Comment: If you just want Latin do p{Latin} instead of p{L}

Answer (score 4):

Here is the regex for what you want with a quantifier to specify at least 1 character and no more than 255 characters

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9 _]{1,255}
```

Answer (score 4):

For me there was an issue in that I want to distinguish between alpha, numeric and alpha numeric, so to ensure an alphanumeric string contains at least one alpha and at least one numeric, I used :

```
^([a-zA-Z_]{1,}\d{1,})+|(\d{1,}[a-zA-Z_]{1,})+$
```

Comment: Exactly what I want... Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are not taking Latin and Unicode characters in your matches.

For example, if you need to take "ã" or "ü" chars, the use of "\w" won't work.

You can, alternatively, use this approach:

```
^[A-ZÀ-Ýa-zà-ý0-9_]+$
```

Answer (score 2):

`^\w*$` will work for the below combinations:

```
1
123
1av
pRo
av1
```

Comment: What about an empty line. Is it also an alphanumeric string?

Answer (score 2):

For Java, *only* case insensitive alphanumeric and underscore are allowed.

- ^ Matches the string starting with any characters
- [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ Matches alpha-numeric character and underscore.
- $ Matches the string ending with zero or more characters.

  ```java
    public class RegExTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("_C#".matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$"));
        }
    }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

To check the entire string and not allow empty strings, try

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. You can try:

```
[\\p{Alnum}_]
```

Comment: I try this and I get unknown property Alnum, where is this defined?

Answer (score -1):

#### Required Format

Allow these three:

1. 0142171547295
2. 014-2171547295
3. 123abc

Don't allow other formats:

```js
validatePnrAndTicketNumber(){
    let alphaNumericRegex=/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
    let numericRegex=/^[0-9]*$/;
    let numericdashRegex=/^(([1-9]{3})\-?([0-9]{10}))$/;
   this.currBookingRefValue = this.requestForm.controls["bookingReference"].value;
   if(this.currBookingRefValue.length == 14 && this.currBookingRefValue.match(numericdashRegex)){
     this.requestForm.controls["bookingReference"].setErrors({'pattern': false});
   }else if(this.currBookingRefValue.length ==6 && this.currBookingRefValue.match(alphaNumericRegex)){
    this.requestForm.controls["bookingReference"].setErrors({'pattern': false});
   }else if(this.currBookingRefValue.length ==13 && this.currBookingRefValue.match(numericRegex) ){
    this.requestForm.controls["bookingReference"].setErrors({'pattern': false});
   }else{
    this.requestForm.controls["bookingReference"].setErrors({'pattern': true});
   }
}
```

```html
<input name="booking_reference" type="text" [class.input-not-empty]="bookingRef.value"
    class="glyph-input form-control floating-label-input" id="bookings_bookingReference"
    value="" maxlength="14" aria-required="true" role="textbox" #bookingRef
    formControlName="bookingReference" (focus)="resetMessageField()" (blur)="validatePnrAndTicketNumber()"/>
```