# How to check for special characters in a string using a loop

Tags: c#, string, loops

since my prof won't let me use RegEx, I'm stuck with using loops to check each character on a string.
Does anyone have a sample code/algorithm?

```
public void setAddress(string strAddress)
{
    do
    {
        foreach (char c in Name)
        {
            if ( /*check for characters*/ == false)
            {
                Address = strAddress;
            }
        }
        if ( /*check for characters*/ == true)
        {
            Console.Write("Invalid!");
        }
    } while ( /*check for characters*/ == true)
}
public int getAddress()
{
    return Address;
}
```

I need to only include letters and numbers. Characters such as !@#$%^& are not allowed.
I'm not allowed to use RegEx because he hasn't taught that to us yet... well I couldn't attend class on the day he taught these loops and character checking, so now he won't tell me more. ANYWAY, if there's a more efficient way without using RegEx, that'd be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean "special character"?

Comment: Can you show what invalid characters you are checking for.. also I don't see the need to do a do while loop combined with a foreach loop.. you can do this with a foreaach or a for loop just as easy or use a linq statement

Comment: `since my prof won't let me use RegEx` - you should tell him, as a programmer, you use whatever solves the problem in the most efficient way.

Comment: like !@#$%^&*() and the likes. ANything that aren't letters or numbers basically.

Comment: if you insist on a for loop look at this link.. also try to think outside the box a little bit.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208688/quickest-way-to-enumerate-the-alphabet-in-c-sharp

Comment: Difficult to think outside the box when you have a fever and still boligated to go to class :) but thanks!

Comment: Is there no textbook you could reference?

Answer (score 5):

```
        string s = @"$KUH% I*$)OFNlkfn$";
        var withoutSpecial = new string(s.Where(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) 
                                            || Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray());

        if (s != withoutSpecial)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("String contains special chars");
        }
```

You can do it without loops at all :)

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4503614/1714342

EDIT:

```
if(s.Any(c=>c => !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
{
    Console.WriteLine("String contains special chars");
}
```

Comment: also worth noting, that there will of course be loops - just hidden inside of the linq-part. Still, a very neat solution!

Comment: @Chips_100 Of course there are loops below in linq, but you are not writing them by yourself. Loops are everywhere :D

Comment: Side note: [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) is better for given task... Either approach unlikely to help OP so :) - but good answer for SO.

Comment: Ah, he'd likely question how I managed to come up with that solution without a loop. Although I might be able to use this in a future date.

Answer (score 2):

You may not need loops at all, just character checking will do:

```
if (Name.IndexofAny("!@#$%^&*()".ToCharArray() != -1))
    Console.WriteLine("Valid Address");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Address");
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexofany.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A solution with explicit loop could be

```
  String s = @"$KUH% I*$)OFNlkfn$"; 

  foreach (Char c in s) 
    if (!(Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))) {
      Console.WriteLine("String contains special chars");

      break;
    }
```

Comment: I might be able to edit the code a bit if I use this, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
bool check_for_characters(char c)
{
 return (c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
}
```