# How could I check for no "!@#$%^&*,Etc" in a string?

Tags: c#

Hey sorry for the messy title, However I cannot really find the right definition for this group of sings (!@#$%^&*()_+?><), however, there is any way I would be able to check if my string contain any  of those sings?
I was really struggling, And honestly I was tryng to do it using a very messy "if" mentioned below:

> if (c == '!' || c == '@' || c == '#' || c == '$' || c == '%' || c ==
>   '^' || c == '&' || c == '*' || c == '(' || c == ')' || c == '*' || c
>   == '*' || c == '+'
>                               || c == '{' || c == '}' || c == '/' || c == '>' || c == '<' || c == '>' || c == '~' || c == '`' || c == '?' || c == ':' || c == '"')

Im sure there is a better way to check it, but I do not know any function that could check it.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: regex is  your good friend

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check for special characters (/\*-+\_@&$#%) in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503542/check-for-special-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: What about other Unicode characters? Do you perhaps actually want a whitelist?

Comment: If you don't want to use regex, you can use `IndexOfAny`. Something like: `c.IndexOfAny("!@#$%^&*()_+?><".ToCharArray()) != -1`

Comment: it is a lot that you are looking for. What is the complementary set? meaning the alternative? only letters and numbers? maybe it is easier to check for those ?=!

Answer (score -1):

You could probably use Regex.

```
// text here refers to your entire string
if (Regex.Matches(text, @"[!@#$%^&*()_+?><]"))
{
    // do something
}
```

Something similar to that should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of understanding,but 'c' inside the "Regex.Matches" reffers to a char "c"? And if so, it should be  running inside "for" or "foreach" loop, right?

Comment: I beliveve my regex was actually wrong. Yes the c was supposed to refer to the string you were talking about, not each individual character.