# How can I identify special characters in a string? C#

Tags: c#, string, encoding, substring, special-characters

I'm trying to get all characters in a string that occur before a certain character.

For example:

```
string id = "Hello everyone! Good day today.";
id = id.Remove(id.IndexOf('!'));
Console.WriteLine(id);
//output will be "Hello everyone"
```

And this works, but when I'm reading text from a special file and working with strings that contain special characters, I run into some trouble.

For example:

```
string id = "Hello everybodyø1Ø9ß&ëÄ"
```

If I wanted to only get the "Hello everybody" text, how would I do that? These special characters can be anything.

Comment: Define "special" (other than "anything")

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120198/most-efficient-way-to-remove-special-characters-from-string

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be to specify the allowed chars and use `Enumerable.TakeWhile`:

```
string id = "Hello everybodyø1Ø9ß&ëÄ";
string allowedChars = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
string result = string.Concat(id.TakeWhile(allowedChars.Contains)); // Hello everybody
```

Or use `Regex` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503542/check-for-special-characters-in-a-string)(which just checks if there are special chars).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        string[] KeepCharacters = { "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"," ", "~","`","!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","-","_","+","=",@"\","|","}","]","{","[","'",":",";","/","?",".",">",",","<","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0", Convert.ToString((char)34)};
        string id = "Hello everybodyø1Ø9ß&ëÄ";

        for(int i =0; i < id.Length; i++)
        {
            if(KeepCharacters.Contains(id.Substring(i,1).ToLower()) == false)
            {
                id = id.Remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an extension method added to `string` and use it as you wish.

Also note that I used `StringBuilder` since it doesn't create a new object in the memory but dynamically expands memory to accommodate the modified string (in contrast of doing it via regular string concatenation which could effect performance on long strings)

```js
public static string GetRegularString(this string str) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   foreach (char c in str) {
      if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || c == '.' || c == '_' || c == ' ') {
         sb.Append(c);
      }
      else{
        break;
      }
   }
   return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked into it and found my own solution that works like a charm

```
id = id.Remove(id.IndexOf(id.Where(x => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(x)).First()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add Regex namespace. It allows replacing a special character with your desired character/number/symbol.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string id = "Hello everybodyø1Ø9ß&ëÄ";
        string op = string.Empty;
        Console.WriteLine("i/p is " + id );
        Regex rgx = new Regex("[^A-Za-z0-9]");
        for (int i = 0; i < id.Length; i++)
        {
           bool isNUmber = int.TryParse(id[i].ToString(), out int n);
           op += (rgx.IsMatch(id[i].ToString()) || isNUmber  ) ? " " : id[i].ToString();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("O/p is " + op);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

for more information : https://techstrology.com/c-sharp-if-string-contains-space-or-special-character/

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of Regex under **System.Text.RegularExpression**. This reference should be added to the program file. This code helps to check whether the string contains a special character or not, new **Regex(“[^A-Za-z0-9]”)** and this helps to check whether the string consists of special charaters or not. There is a function called **IsMatch()** which return true when the string consists of special characters.

```
        string temp = "sathee *d@@lkr:d";
        Regex rgx = new Regex("[^A-Za-z0-9]");
        bool hasSpecialChars = rgx.IsMatch(temp);
```