# Is there any regular expression pattern to match a excel sheet name and address i.e. cell reference

Tags: regex, c#-3.0

Some valid sheeet names  are as under among the other various names

```
t'#3cfbsdjfdsjb''''''''^^^^^^&&'!$C$8:$N$23   

1'!$E$13:$H$19    

!'!$B$7:$E$16    

@@@@@@@'!$B$7:$K$21

!$'!$B$12:$M$17
```

Iam using

```
string pattern =@"[^<]+?\!\$[A-Z]+\$[0-9]+"

Regex r = new Regex(Constants.CELL_REFERENCE_PATTERN);
            Match m = r.Match(selectedVal);
            if (m.Success) return true;
            else return false;
```

but it is failing for

> "t'#3cfbsdjfdsjb''''''''^^^^^^&&'!$C$8:$N$23,p,mv" or "sheeet1!$A1."

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like `.+` would include all those.

Answer (score 5):

Ignoring the C# factor, these are regular expressions that I have found to work.

Cell Reference with sheet optional (<sheet>!<cell>)

```
"(('[^/\\?*\[\]]{1,31}'|[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,31})!)?((\$?[A-Za-z]{1,3})(\$?[0-9]{1,6}))"
```

Notes:

- This regex does not validate Cell values, ex. `ZZZ999999` is valid through the regex, but it is not a valid location inside of Excel.
- This is for Excel 2007+. For pre-2007, change `{1,3}` to `{1,2}` and `{1,6}` to `{1,5}`. This is because the range of cells went from `IV65536` (pre-2007) to `XFD1048576` (2007+). But of course, there is no validation and technically it could be `[A-Za-z]+` and `[0-9]+`.

Comment: `A-Za-z_` doesn't work for "Sheet1" you need digits as well (so A-Za-z1-9_)

Comment: @flutefreak7, good catch! I updated it and included support for `0`

Comment: I was thinking `\w` might work, but apparently it varies in meaning and even in .Net requires some options to limit its behavior to only alpha-nuneric and underscore rather than including other Unicode characters. http://stackoverflow.com/a/336220/1639671. While I'm here... If the sheet has spaces you'll also need `''` around the sheet...

Comment: @flutefreak7, that's exactly why I explicitly defined the character classes. It's a very common issue with regex that most people don't know or remember off hand. As for the spaces, it's taken care of in the first half of the sheet section: `'[^/\\?*\[\]]{1,31}'`

Comment: still missing a lot:
such as space, or column scope C:D, rows scope 1:99...

Answer (score 1):

I do not know a lot about C# but in most Regexp API Match and Search are distinct.

1. Match means that the string have to match the whole pattern
2. Search means that the string contains the pattern

In your case

```
@"[^<]+?\!\$[A-Z]+\$[0-9]+"

"t'#3cfbsdjfdsjb''''''''^^^^^^&&'!$C$8:$N$23,p,mv"
```

Probably match very probably only

```
"t'#3cfbsdjfdsjb''''''''^^^^^^&&'!$C$8"
```

Try this Regex instead :
   @"[^<]+?!\$[A-Z]+\$[0-9]+.*"

Usually when I do not understand why a Regex does not work I split it in several simpler part.

It is also a good practice to test them in a tiny Unit Test.

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this while looking for office-js / general JavaScript solution, use this one:

`('.{1,31}'|[\w.]{1,31}?)!(([\w$].*?):([\w$]*)|([\w$].*))`

Below is a link to a unit test with the author's sheet names.
https://regex101.com/r/IDF2g6/6