# Can anyone tell me the regex for excluding numbers and special characters in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, regex

How do I get the regular expression for excluding special charaters and numbers?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define "special character". Is `é` a special character? How about `商`?

Comment: Is space a spacial character? The question would be much more answerable with a few valid/invalid examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression for alphanumeric and underscores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336210/regular-expression-for-alphanumeric-and-underscores)

Comment: The special charaters are here " ( )[ ]{ }*& ^ % $ # @ !"  please privide me the solution

Answer (score 6):

Try the following: `^[a-zA-Z]*$`

Answer (score 4):

possible regex

```
[^()[\]{}*&^%$#@!]+
```

this will match anything but `()[]{}*&^%$#@!`

the `[^...]+` is a "any character except ..." and the `]` must be escaped with `\]`

http://www.myregextester.com/?r=37f5dfd3