# How to create a regex for accepting only  alphanumeric characters?

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular Expression for alphanumeric and underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336210/regular-expression-for-alphanumeric-and-underscores)

How to create a regex for accepting only alphanumeric characters?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336210/regular-expression-for-alphanumeric-and-underscores

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]*$` the '-' must be the last thing in case you need it too

Answer (score 113):

Try below Alphanumeric regex

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
```

^ - Start of string

[a-zA-Z0-9]* - multiple characters to include

$ - End of string

See more: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: This will also match an EMPTY string, which may not be desirable in most situations. To counter that simply replace the trailing `*` with `+` So basically it's `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` to avoid false positives generated by empty strings. You can also text your regex at https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 28):

[a-zA-Z0-9] will only match ASCII characters, it won't match

```
String target = new String("A" + "\u00ea" + "\u00f1" +
                             "\u00fc" + "C");
```

If you also want to match unicode characters:

```
String pat = "^[\\p{L}0-9]*$";
```

Comment: Given +1 for Unicode, as this is often overlooked.

Answer (score 18):

Only ASCII or are other characters allowed too?

```
^\w*$
```

restricts (in Java) to ASCII letters/digits und underscore,

```
^[\pL\pN\p{Pc}]*$
```

also allows international characters/digits and "connecting punctuation".

Comment: Note: it's important to say that \w accepts underscore.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

try with \w

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html

Comment: this is old but just so people know, this also matches underscores

Answer (score 3):

Use this `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$`

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336210/regular-expression-for-alphanumeric-and-underscores) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

for example [A-Za-z0-9]

Comment: this will accept only numbers as well