# How to write a regex to match this String in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to make a regular expression to the following string :

```
String s = "fdrt45B45";     // s is a password (just an example) with only 
                            // letters and digits(must have letters and digits)
```

I tried with this pattern:

```
String pattern= "^(\\w{1,}|\\d{1,})$";     //but it doesn't work
```

I want to get a not match if my password doesn't contains letters or digits and a match if its contains both.

I know that: `\w is a word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]` and `\d is a digit: [0-9]`, but i can not mix `\w and \d` to get what i want. Any help or tips is very appreciated for a newbie.

Comment: Its a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988228/how-to-create-a-regex-for-accepting-only-alphanumeric-characters.

Comment: google such questions on SO before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A positive lookahead would do the trick :

```
String s = "fdrt45B45";
System.out.println(s.matches("(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]+"));
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm and I am trying to understand the expression.

Comment: @dustin -  `(?=.*[something])` is called *positive look ahead*. It looks for *something* but doesn't move the *pointer / reference* to point to something. The first 2 `?=` checks start from length `0` . Your actual character *capture* starts from `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. The first 2 expressions are *look and forget* kind. Got it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following regex to achieve what you want.  This uses a positive look ahead and will match any string containing at least one letter and at least one number.

```
^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*\\w).*
```

Comment: Please note that `\w` doesn't mean "all letters", it means "all letters, digits, and underscore" (`[a-zA-Z_0-9]`). So your regex is matching an unwanted password. [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html)

Comment: @olambert: it dosen't work with only digits (i have a match with only digits), otherwise it is fine.

Comment: OK, I think I misunderstood what you were trying to do - I thought you wanted to enforce that the password had both letters and digits. If you just want to match a password with letters or digits, you could just use `^[0-9A-Za-z]+$`

Comment: @olambert: I think I misunderstood what you were trying to do - I thought you wanted to enforce that the password had both letters and digits...**this is what i want to**, but with: `^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*\\w).*` i get a match with only digits!! - **Thanks anyway for trying to help me**