# Regex to accept only alphanumeric data

Tags: java, regex

I want to validate the input data to allow only alphanumeric value. It should not be only numbers or only alphabets. How to do that using regex expression in Java?

Comment: You can find another resolve ways here
[How to create a regex for accepting only alphanumeric characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988228/how-to-create-a-regex-for-accepting-only-alphanumeric-characters)

Answer (score 2):

You can very easily find the character class for alphanumeric characters in the [Pattern javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> `\p{Alnum}`   An alphanumeric character: `[\p{Alpha}\p{Digit}]`

Comment: why you provide an answer when OP does not have any research efforts?

Comment: @codegasmer sometimes a little nudge in the right direction helps.

Comment: thanks Andy .. i have tried this way  a.matches("^[A-Za-z0-9]+$") but this allows data with numbers also .. can u suggest few other ways as well

Comment: Oh, sorry - *only* numbers **OR** *only* alphabets? That's not really what alphanumeric data is. You should really try to work out how to do it yourself from the Javadoc (look for "Logical operators").

Comment: should allow only alphanumeric input not just the alphabets or numbers