# Regex to retrieve any alphanumeric otp code

Tags: java, regex, alphanumeric, one-time-password

I am trying to get a regex to retrieve alphanumeric OTP code (length of the code maybe dynamic i.e depending on user's choice) and must contain at least one digit.

I have tried the following regex :
 "[a-zA-z]*[0-9].[a-zA-z]*"

But if a special character is there in the code it should result null instead it retrieves the characters before and after the special character which is not desired.

Some sample OTP-containing messages on which the regex is desired to work successfully:

1. OTP is **** for txn of INR 78.90.
2. **** is your one-time password.
3. Hi, Your OTP is ****.

Examples of Alphanumeric OTPs with at least one-digit:

1. 78784
2. aZ837
3. 987Ny
4. 19hd35
5. fc82pl

Comment: You can check these links. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336210/regular-expression-for-alphanumeric-and-underscores , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988228/how-to-create-a-regex-for-accepting-only-alphanumeric-characters/5988385

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be a bit difficult, maybe this expression might work with an `i` flag:

```
[a-z0-9]*\d[a-z0-9]*
```

or with word boundaries:

```
(?<=\b)[a-z0-9]*\d[a-z0-9]*(?=\b)
```

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "[a-z0-9]*\\d[a-z0-9]*";
final String string = "78784\n"
     + "aZ837\n"
     + "987Ny\n"
     + "19hd35\n"
     + "fc82pl";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/7dBvJV/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/7dBvJV/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Comment: I'd encapsulate it with lookbehind (?<=\b) and lookahead (?=\b) just to avoid some false positives, but otherwise it look good.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
[0-9a-zA-Z]*[0-9]+[0-9a-zA-Z]*
```

This evaluates your desired result.

I have tested this in [this site](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is almost correct.
It should be `\b[a-zA-z]*[0-9]+[a-zA-z0-9]*\b`.