# No ending delimiter '/' found error

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink, preg-match

I have adjusted a small script to check backlinks. Yet I keep on getting the error

Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '/' found in line 17.

```
<?php
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}

function google_backlink($uri)
{
$url = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=link:facebook.com&hl=en&filter=0';
$v = file_get_contents_curl($url);
preg_match('/<div id="resultStats">About \(.*?)\ ',$v,$s);
$s_number = explode(".", $s[1]);
$i = 0;
if ($s[1]!=0) {
    return $s[1];
} else {
    return ($r[1]) ? $r[1] : '0';
}
}

echo "Google backlink = ".google_backlink($url)."<br />";   
?>
```

What is wrong with
`preg_match('/<div id="resultStats">About \(.*?)\ ',$v,$s);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is very clear really, you didn't include the trailing `/`:

```
preg_match('/<div id="resultStats">About \(.*?)\ /',$v,$s);
```

I honestly doubt your escape characters are well placed though. Maybe you meant `\)`?

Comment: easy fix: replace that line with this: `preg_match('/<div id="resultStats">About \(.*?\) /',$v,$s);`. This is probably wrong though, my guess is you want this: `preg_match('/<div id="resultStats">About (.*?)/',$v,$s);`. The last space and escaped parentheses means it will match `About (something) `, and not `About something` or `About (something)`.

Comment: @Jesse, I'd be better suited to appreciate your answer if I knew the question too. Care to enlighten me?

Comment: Thank you, this gives Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 33

Comment: @Lisa, Yes, because you're escaping the opening parentheses, but not the closing ones, so they're unbalanced.

Comment: preg_match('/<div id="resultStats">About (.*?)/',$v,$s); solved the error. Thank you. Now I just need to fix the code, but this error was fixed. :)

Comment: @Blindy - sorry, just trying to clarify without making a new answer. I figured it was worth putting some samples up, and making sure the ending space was on purpose.

Comment: @Jesse, it wasn't, but it wasn't for us to decide :)

Answer (score 9):

It does not have a closing /

`preg_match('/ pattern /', $subject);`

You have a beginning (slash) `/` but no closing (slash) `/`

It looks for the pattern you define in between the 2 slashes.

Comment: This is the most educating answer. Now I understand the error, thank you.

Comment: @Lisa then vote my answer as being correct by giving me a green check by checking the "check". Or upvote me. I want points. We survive off of points ma'am. :-D

Comment: I tried the closing slash, but that just gives the following error:

Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 33

Comment: preg_match('/<div id="resultStats">About (.*?)/',$v,$s); solved the error. solved the error, but I can only vote once :( how can I also give you credit?

Comment: @Lisa there should be a "checkbox" under the number. Just hover over the checkbox, and it'll turn green. And when it turns green, click it. OH, you mean you've already chose a correct answer. OMG. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Try changing
`preg_match('/<div id="resultStats">About \(.*?)\ ',$v,$s);`

To
`preg_match('/<div id="resultStats">About \(.*?)\ /',$v,$s);`

`/` is a "delimiter" meaning it tells preg_match where the regex pattern ends.