# Regex of validating must contain alphanumerics

Tags: java, regex

I want to make a regex that must have atlease one number and one alphabet.

`onlyText` will not math. But `onlyText123` matches.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336210/regular-expression-for-alphanumeric-and-underscores this minus the underscores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\d]).*$
```

The key is to use a technique called **lookaround**

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
String p= "\\w*([a-zA-Z]\\d|\\d[a-zA-Z])\\w*";

System.out.println("1a".matches(p));//true
System.out.println("a1".matches(p));//true
System.out.println("1".matches(p));//false
System.out.println("a".matches(p));//false
```

`([a-zA-Z]\\d|\\d[a-zA-Z])` == letter then number OR number then letter

and before and after it can (but don't have to) be letters and digits (`\\w`)