# Replacing symbol characters in PostgreSQL

Tags: xml, regex, postgresql, replace, invalid-characters

I have data that contains a note field that is full of invalid characters due to a faulty exporting tool and imported from an excel spreadsheet (*.xls).

The character is erroring out in XML, saying Character reference "&#xb" is an invalid XML character.

How would I go about replacing wingdings characters such as:  Gender signs, blocks, symbols in PostgreSQL?

I tried in vain to copy and paste these characters into a replace statement, or anything for that matter, and it was futile.  Is there a way through RegExp to replace any non-alphanumeric or "-=+" type of characters?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336210/regular-expression-for-alphanumeric-and-underscores

Comment: Please show your PostgreSQL version in future posts. different versions have different capabilities, so it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT regexp_replace('123xabcABCxöäüxÖÄÜx¡‘’xæćčx=+-x"§$%&/()x'
                     ,'[^a-zA-Z0-9=+-]','_','g')
```

Result:

```
123xabcABCx___x___x___x___x=+-x________x
```

The leading `^` in the character class `[^a-zA-Z0-9=+-]` negates it. Read "all characters *not* in the following list".

Take care to place the `-` character at the end (or beginning) of the character class, or it will have a special meaning like in `a-z`.

Note the 4th parameter `'g'` for "globally". Without it, only the first match would be replaced.

Note also, how characters like `öäü` get replaced as well. You may or may not want that ...
Therefore, you may be interested in the `unaccent` extension that provides the [`unaccent()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/unaccent.html#AEN138587) function:

> The unaccent() function removes accents (diacritic signs) from a given
>   string.

Details about PostgreSQL regular expression in the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP).