# Regular Expression does not allowing underscore

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex

Below regex is not allowing email id with underscore like myName_6@a.com

```
@"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.w]*[0-9a-zA-Z_])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-w]*[0-9a-zA-Z].)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$"
```

any idea?

Comment: `0-9a-zA-Z` does indeed not allow an underscore

Comment: yes, want to allow underscore in it

Comment: ' "^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.w]*[0-9a-zA-Z_])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-w]*[0-9a-zA-Z].)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$" '

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression for alphanumeric and underscores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336210/regular-expression-for-alphanumeric-and-underscores)

Comment: `@"^([0-9a-zA-Z_]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][-w][0-9a-zA-Z].)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no underscore anywhere in the regexp, which accounts for it not matching underscores. Try adding an underscore to the list of allowed characters to the left of the `@`-sign.

Comment: Could have just linked to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336210/regular-expression-for-alphanumeric-and-underscores)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/
```