# regular expression to check a symbol

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a text box to input.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_namepair" runat="server" Text="<Name>=<Value>">
</asp:TextBox>
```

I want to add validation using regular expression validator. Now I need regular expression  to check  the input format as

```
"alpha numeric string = alphanumeric string"  
 like <name>=<value> pairs.
```

When I click on add button those = pairs will be displayed in a listbox.But what I wanted is, I want to check whether those , pairs have equal sign(=) between them by using regular expression. And  and  pairs should be alpha numeric characters.

Comment: You can have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/336220/1012641) on SO and modify it as per your needs. The user here has explained everything well

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*=[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$
```

to match your string

```
"alpha numeric string = alphanumeric string"
```

P.S. Do you really need spaces? If not delete the space from the regular expression after 9.

You can test the code I have provided at the following site
http://regexhero.net/tester/

Comment: @user2181131:Can you mark this as an answer and up-vote it if it met your requirements?