# Regex for validating a string that contains combination of alphabets and numbers

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need a regular expression to check that a string contains combination of alphabets and numbers.Special characters and space is not allowed.my string should contain atleast one character and one alphabet

Comment: Have you tried anything? I think regular expressions are pretty good covered with tutorials and examples, maybe you should use a search engine...

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? This is quite a bit vague... http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ might be a start for you ;)

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Regular Expression for alphanumeric and underscores](http://stackoverflow.com/q/336210/781965)

Comment: my string should contain atleast one character and one alphabet

Comment: That's something you should mention in your question, not just in a comment. Not everyone reads those. Also, define "alphabets" and "numbers". Does `ä` count?

Comment: What do you mean by `one character and one alphabet`?

Answer (score 4):

## Description

This will

- find all strings which have at least one letter and one number
- and only contain letters and numbers in any order

`^(?=[^\s]*?[0-9])(?=[^\s]*?[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`

[image]

## Example

Note for some of these examples I have removed the `$` at the end of the expression as source string in the example really contains many lines. To properly validate the string you'll need to remove the multiline matching and use the `$` character as shown above.

[Live Example](http://www.rubular.com/r/vapOCfQC6m)

**Sample Text**

```
11
22
33
1
2
3
1a
2b
3c
a1
b2
c3
1a1a
2b2b
3b3b
1a1
2b2
3b3
a1a
b2b
c3c
a
b
c
aa
bb
cc
```

**C# Code Example**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace myapp
{
  class Class1
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
          Regex re = new Regex(@"^(?=[^\s]*?[0-9])(?=[^\s]*?[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline);
          MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(sourcestring);
          int mIdx=0;
          foreach (Match m in mc)
           {
            for (int gIdx = 0; gIdx < m.Groups.Count; gIdx++)
              {
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames()[gIdx], m.Groups[gIdx].Value);
              }
            mIdx++;
          }
        }
    }
}
```

**Matches Found**

```
[0][0] = 1a
[1][0] = 2b
[2][0] = 3c
[3][0] = a1
[4][0] = b2
[5][0] = c3
[6][0] = 1a1a
[7][0] = 2b2b
[8][0] = 3b3b
[9][0] = 1a1
[10][0] = 2b2
[11][0] = 3b3
[12][0] = a1a
[13][0] = b2b
[14][0] = c3c
```

## Summary

This works because the expression looks ahead to validate it can indeed find a number and a letter in the string, then matches all letters and numbers

Answer (score 3):

In order to be unicode compatible:

```
^[\pL\pN]+$
```

`\pL` stands for any letter
`\pN` stands for any digit

Comment: what about any symbol?

Comment: @Question_Guy: Just add them in the character class.

Answer (score 2):

To match just a single 0-9 or a-z or A-Z.

```
[0-9a-zA-Z]
```

To match 1 or more

```
[0-9a-zA-Z]\+
```

And if you are interested in the entire line being alphanumeric characters.

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z]\+$
```

The ^ matches the beginning of the line and the $ matches the end of the line.

Comment: Just in case it's useful to the OP, you can use `*` to denote 0 or more (if the empty string is acceptable)

Comment: my string should contain atleast one character and one alphabet

Comment: What's up with the `\+` ?  We're using .NET regexes, not grep.