# How to check a string for a special character?

Tags: python, string

I can only use a string in my program if it contains no special characters except underscore `_`. How can I check this?

I tried using unicodedata library. But the special characters just got replaced by standard characters.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use `string.punctuation` and `any` function like this

```
import string
invalidChars = set(string.punctuation.replace("_", ""))
if any(char in invalidChars for char in word):
    print "Invalid"
else:
    print "Valid"
```

With this line

```
invalidChars = set(string.punctuation.replace("_", ""))
```

we are preparing a list of punctuation characters which are not allowed. As you want `_` to be allowed, we are removing `_` from the list and preparing new set as `invalidChars`. Because lookups are faster in sets.

`any` function will return `True` if atleast one of the characters is in `invalidChars`.

**Edit:** As asked in the comments, this is the regular expression solution. Regular expression taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/336220/1903116

```
word = "Welcome"
import re
print "Valid" if re.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$", word) else "Invalid"
```

Comment: How can we use regular expression for this same question?? sorry to bother yu... im jus a beginner..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41158/discussion-between-chuvi-and-thefourtheye)

Comment: @Awknewbie Include space also in the RegEx like this `"^[a-zA-Z0-9 _]*$"`

Comment: Isn't the regex `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]*$` with the `^` inside the brackets? That's what worked for me

Answer (score 6):

You will need to define "special characters", but it's likely that for some string `s` you mean:

```
import re
if re.match(r'^\w+$', s):
    # s is good-to-go
```

Comment: Returns True for white space

Answer (score 0):

Everyone else's method **doesn't account for whitespaces**. Obviously nobody really considers a whitespace a special character.

Use this method to detect special characters *not including whitespaces*:

```
import re

def detect_special_characer(pass_string): 
  regex= re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]') 
  if(regex.search(pass_string) == None): 
    res = False
  else: 
    res = True
  return(res)
```

Comment: That regex cant find any occurance of [ and bunch of others

Answer (score 0):

Like the method from [Cybernetic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639594/cybernetic), to get those extra characters missed, modify the 2nd line of the function from

`regex= re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')`

to

`regex= re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\\|}{~:\[\]]')`

where the `\` and `]` characters are escaped with `\`

So in full:

```
import re

def detect_special_characer(pass_string): 
  regex= re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\\\|}{~:[\]]') 
  if(regex.search(pass_string) == None): 
    res = False
  else: 
    res = True
  return(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

If a character is not numeric, a space, or is A-Z, then it is special

```py
for character in my_string
   if not (character.isnumeric() and character.isspace() and character.isalpha() and character != "_")
       print(" \(character)is special"
```