# Count the line only when special characters are present

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

I want to count the line only when special characters are present in the line.

```
count=0
with open (xvg_input, 'r') as cavity_count:
    line_to_end = cavity_count.readlines()
    for line in line_to_end:
        if "#" in line and "@" in line:
            count +=1
        print (count)
```

Just want to count the lines when there is a special character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check a string for a special character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970532/how-to-check-a-string-for-a-special-character)

Comment: Whats the question here?  Whats your input look like?

Comment: Right now your code counts lines that have both `@` and `#` only

Comment: `if re.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$", line): count+=1`

Comment: @    xaxis  label "Frame"
@    yaxis  label "Volume (Angstroms\S3\N)"
@ s0 legend "Total"
@ s1 legend "Cavity 1"
@ s2 legend "Cavity 2"

Comment: still the count is zero .

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming, you want to count total number of lines where the special characters were present. If that is the case then move out the print. It is indented two levels inside.

Very slight change in your code (if all you care is to count "#" or "@", else please let us know).

```py
count=0
with open (xvg_input, 'r') as cavity_count:
    line_to_end = cavity_count.readlines()
    for line in line_to_end:
        if "#" in line or "@" in line:
            count +=1
print(count)
```

However if you instead wanted to count some other property then this method will not work. Please let us know, if this is not what you wanted.

Comment: I also tried this one but still the count is coming as Zero.

Comment: Do you expect "#" and "@" to be present together in the same line or you expect any one of them to be present?

Comment: any of them gonna be present

Comment: literally it was stupid mistake :( :(. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
from string import punctuation
with open(xvg_input, 'r') as cavity_count:
    print(len(
             ['' for line in cavity_count
                if any(char in line for char in punctuation)]
          ))
```

Or if you want to make smth with that count just save it to any var instead of printing

Comment: it is counting whole lines.

Comment: why? It checks if any of punctuation characters is in the line so it won't count lines which have no punctuation chars.