# I created an empty list. Take words from the user. Give the total number of words greater then 5

Tags: python, list

Any mistake is there?

```
list1 = []
len = int(input('Enter the lenght you want : '))
for k in range(len):
    alp = input('Enter your word : ')
    list1.append(alp)
print()
print('The original List : ' , list1)

temp1 = 0
temp2 = 0

words = alp.split(" ")
for word in  words:
    if len(word) >= 5:
        temp1 += 1
    else :
        temp2 += 1

print(temp1)
print(temp2)
```

Comment: I have tagged this has Python. Please retag if that is not correct.

Comment: Please also explain what problem you are having with the code, in the question itself.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community. Please elaborate on your problem.

Comment: Why you are iterating over `words`. Shouldn't it be `list1`?

Comment: You have overwritten the `len` function. Don't do this.

Comment: That and `words = alp.split(" ")` - `alp` is the last inputted word.  Just iterate over the list: `for word in list1:`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the corrected version:

```
words = [] # try to use more descriptive variable names ('list1' is not clear, 'words' is better)

num_words = int(input('Enter the length you want : '))

for k in range(num_words):
    words.append(input('Enter your word : ')) # directly append the inputted word, no need for an intermediate variable

print()
print('The original List : ' , words)

result = 0

for word in words: # no need to split words, as it is already a list of words
    if len(word) >= 5:
        result += 1 # only count if it is longer than 5 characters

print(result)
```

As other commenters have mentioned, avoid renamed reserved names such as `len`, because this leads to mistakes.

Comment: I don't know sir that what is up vote or down vote ?

Comment: Small up arrow (or triangle) to the left of the answer. No worries though.

Comment: Respected sir, I am writing a program to check the type of the variable like Digit,uppercase,lower case, special char. But I have functions like isupper(),is lower(),isdigit().But I am unable to find any function for a "Special char". How can I check a special char in the shortest way ? Kindly help me out with ?

Comment: @Ãlok see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970532/how-to-check-a-string-for-a-special-character