# Regular expression for hashtag text with multi language support

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, regex

I have a texts like **#sample_123** , **#123_sample** , **#_sample123** so i have to use regular expression to check the text contains only alphanumeric and underscore and also i want to support multi languages.

Currently i am using regular expression like `(#)([:alpha:]+)` but it detects only #sample( eg: **#sample**_123). So, Can any one please suggest the correct regular expression to fix out this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression for alphanumeric and underscores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336210/regular-expression-for-alphanumeric-and-underscores)

Comment: @PiyushDubey i have tried like `(#)(^\\w*$)` but it didnt working other than this, all other options in the link which you r given are only supporting english language. Then how cum you people are marking my question as duplicate ????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
^#(\d|\w|_)+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/jS7DzyWZ8jPMF4Sz)

This would validate any words that start with an hash and contains only alpha numeric characters or underscore. Of course there are no restrictions on how many characters after the hashtag there should be, so for example, a hashtag like **#_** is considered valid, if this is not the wanted behavior please be more detailed on the constraints you want.