# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error again and again with chrome. Though this code works fine with firefox

here is the link to the image of error

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ikiy5eesoxco4n/12_edited.jpg

My code is as follows

```
function weight(w)
{
    var Cap = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    var small = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    var spcl = "~!@#$%^&*()_+[]\{}|;':,./<>?";
    var num = '0123456789';
    var p = [];

    for(var j=0;j<w.length;j++)
        {
        if(Cap.contains(w[j])==true)
            p[j] = Cap.indexOf(w[j]) + 2;
        else if(small.contains(w[j])==true)
            p[j] = small.indexOf(w[j]) + 1;
        else if(num.contains(w[j])==true)
            p[j] = num.indexOf(w[j]);
        else if(spcl.contains(w[j])==true)
            p[j] = 1;
        }

    return _.reduce(p,function(memo, num){ return memo + num; }, 0); 

}
```

i do not understand, why my function `if(Cap.contains(w[j])==true)` is undefined??

Comment: Because strings don't have a `contains` method, this is coming in ES6.

Comment: `String.prototype.contains` is not implemented in all browsers because it's part of the forthcoming ECMAScript 6 standard.

Comment: Thank you ppl. i changed to another code. it worked :)

Comment: You are using .indexOf already, you can replace it to if(Cap.indexOf(w[j])!=-1) { ... }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.prototype.contains` is not implemented in all browsers because it's part of the forthcoming ECMAScript 6 standard.

However, you can easily patch it.

```
if (!String.prototype.contains) {
    String.prototype.contains = function(s, i) {
        return this.indexOf(s, i) != -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As **cookie monster** and **elclanrs** rightly said, 'contains()' is not defined in the ECMAScript standard (in others words, javascript) yet.

However, you can still search strings for values as use this as a conditional statement. Common practice is to use indexOf() and evaluate return value as true for positive values, false for -1. See below for an example:

```
function weight(w)
{
    var Cap = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    var small = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    var spcl = "~!@#$%^&*()_+[]\{}|;':,./<>?";
    var num = '0123456789';
    var p = [];

    for(var j=0;j<w.length;j++)
        {
        if(Cap.indexOf(w[j]) > -1)
            p[j] = Cap.indexOf(w[j]) + 2;
        else if(small.indexOf(w[j]) > -1)
            p[j] = small.indexOf(w[j]) + 1;
        else if(num.indexOf(w[j]) > -1)
            p[j] = num.indexOf(w[j]);
        else if(spcl.indexOf(w[j]) > -1)
            p[j] = 1;
        }

    return _.reduce(p,function(memo, num){ return memo + num; }, 0); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(your_string.indexOf('-') === -1)
   {
    alert("no dash found.");
  }
```

For the alpha numeric you can use a regular expression:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

[Regular Expression for alphanumeric and underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336210/regular-expression-for-alphanumeric-and-underscores)