# Numeric and alpha numeric check in DB2 query

Tags: db2

My requirement is to check whether the value is numeric or alpha numeric in DB2 query, I didn't get any functions available in DB2. so any idea on the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of how you could use the [XQuery function fn:matches() in DB2](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/xqrfnmat.html) to [check for numeric or alphanumeric strings based on a regular expression is documented in one of the answers here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/651/emulate-regexp-like-behaviour-in-db2-sql). The core of the idea is here:

`xmlcast(
     xmlquery('fn:matches($YOUR_STRING,"your pattern")') 
     as integer) = 1`

The question is how you define alphanumeric or numeric. Some good [regular expressions are in this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336210/regular-expression-for-alphanumeric-and-underscores).