# Pandas ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups while trying to extract hashtag from tweet

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to extract hashtags from the tweet column in dataframe. For that, I am using `extractall` with regex, but I am getting

```
ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups
```

Here is my code:

```py
df['tweet.full_text'].str.extractall(r'#.*?(?=\s|$)')
```

Comment: could you provide the data you are using

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thousandoaks/BEMM458_OLD/master/data/ConversationsLean.csv'

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), you need to specify a capture group (i.e., parentheses) for str.extract to, well, extract.

```
df['tweet.full_text'].str.extractall(r'(#[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)')
```

[Regular Expression for alphanumeric and underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336210/regular-expression-for-alphanumeric-and-underscores)

It work like this.
[image]